# Subclassing Gallery widget to create "Ticker" behavior

Tags: android, inheritance, android-gallery

This is mostly a philosophy question, as the actual problem is solved.  The SDK provides a Gallery class.  This Gallery is 90% of what I need, it's just missing 2 things.  One I want to implement an extra Runnable that triggers periodic advances to the next item, and two I need it to animate the scroll between items.

The auto periodic advance was easy.  However I came across major issues implementing the scoll animation between items.  Now I've solved this by override setSelection to essential be a wrapper to onFling.

My background is primarily Python at this point, so this implementation feels kinda dirty to me.  I'm calculating a velocity based on the parents width and then calling onFling(null, null, my_calculated_velocity, 0).  This feels really wrong to me, what if for some reason the way google calculates distance from velocity changes?

Now I look through the source of Gallery, and I see tons of ways that feel a ton better to me:
moveNext
scrollToChild
mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance

None of which are accessible from a subclass of Gallery.  In Python there is no real concept of private, so I find it frustrating to no end that when I subclass something in java I end up having to copy paste 2/3's of the class just to override a single behavior.

So the question is am I doing something wrong that's leading me to attempt to do things in ways that are against the Java grain or can I just expect to be frustrated everytime I sit down to work on an android project and find all the methods that do what I need to be be private or default, rather than public or protected?

Comment: I think you're unfortunate with trying to use `Gallery` for what you want to do. I recently started working with `Gallery` to implement a horizontal menu of `TextView` widgets and I've come to realise it really isn't particularly flexible and is a real PITA to work with. In general, most Android classes which are meant to be easily extended allow more than enough functionality - `Gallery` just happens to be a bad one IMO and I've read a number of things by various people who also don't think it's worth using. I'm currently rethinking things as `Gallery` really doesn't cut it.

Comment: For sure it could be just that `Gallery` is a terribly designed class.  I guess then what is the correct way.  Is there a widget that out of the box is better suited to handling a horizontal list of `TextViews` with the basic behavior I describe?  Perhaps even if it was just more flexible with extension so I can completely avoid `Gallery` in the future?

Comment: "Private" is just the designers way of saying "dont mess about with this function".

Comment: @John: I don't have an answer for what you want to do - my requirement isn't to have my menu texts move automatically and even though it works for me in general `Gallery` just doesn't seem to be of much use other than for images. I suggest you Google for "Android ticker" - I found a few ideas by doing this which use a standard `TextView` set for "marquee" with a repeat limit of forever. Good luck.

Comment: @Richard Oh even though I come from a land where private/public is not enforced I understand the concept.  It's just frustrating to come across implementations of classes that don't account for extending them in ways other than "Copy paste the entire source of the class and rewrite the 5-10 lines you need to change"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gallery is as previously mentioned not a very nice class to extend. A better way here would actually be just getting the source and using that.

FYI the velocity DO change, if the device for some reason locks up momentarily.

You are not doing something wrong, it's the class that is designed wrong/for something else.